# Помогите найти ошибку в функции js

Tags: javascript

```js
function make(...args) {
  var arr = [];
  args.forEach(i => arr.push(i))
  var inner = function(...args2) {
    args2.forEach(i => {
      if (typeof i == 'function') {
        return arr.reduce(i)
      } else {
        arr.push(i);
        return inner;
      }
    });
  }
  return inner;
}

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
make(1, 5)(5)(sum)
```

По итогу должно выдать 11, но выдаёт ошибку
Где я накосячил ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что `return` делается из `callback`, а не из функции, таким образом `inner` возвращает `undefined` всегда.

Вместо `forEach`, здесь проще использовать обычный `for`

```js
function make(...args) {
  var arr = [];
  args.forEach(i => arr.push(i))
  var inner = function(...args2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < args2.length; i++) {
      if (typeof args2[i] == 'function') {
        return arr.reduce(args2[i]);
      } else {
        arr.push(args2[i]);
      }
    };
    return inner;
  }
  return inner;
}

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
console.log(make(1, 5)(5)(sum))
```